# Installing latest version of a package on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I want to run Emacs 23 on Cygwin, but when I install cygwin only emacs21 gets installed. How can I upgrade my existing Cygwin install to use Emacs23? I know emacs 23 is available since it's listed at this link.
http://cygwin.com/packages/emacs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're in the "Select Packages" step of Cygwin Setup:

1. Click on the value in the New column (it will cycle through the install options) in the emacs row
2. Select latest version of emacs (you may also have to check the box in the "Bin" column)

[image: Cygwin Select Packages]

One thing I noticed is that once emacs 23 is installed, Cygwin doesn't give you the option to uninstall it. I had to install emacs 21 and then it allowed me to remove emacs.